Not able to change data type in power query in power bi
I was trying to change a data type in power query in power bi and not able to change it.
I tried adding a row and then changing the data form. What other ways I can try it? Please find attached.enter image description here

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Then click the "Error" and see the error-details in de at the bottom pane of your screen.
As I interpret your attached image, probably it's saying there is going to be a cut off of data as you try to convert currency (e.g. € xx,xx) to int x, therefore losing the latter part of ,xx.

You might just as well convert it fixed decimal number

:

and in table view (outside of data transformations, under the report view) you want to set it to currency


Does that work for you?
